# In Svefn-g-englar by Sigur Rós, what is "Tjú"?

Tags: meaning

For years I've been a fan of the song from their second album, Ágætis byrjun. When I look for the English translation, everything is translated, except for the "chorus":

> I'm back
>
> Inside of you
>
> It's so nice to be here
>
> It's just a quick stop
>
> I fly around in underwater
>
> On hotel connected to Electrical Tables and feeds
>
> tju tju

But what is `tju`? Google Translate just gives me the same word back. I assume it's a vocalisation, like "Ooooh", or maybe a "yeaaah", but it could be an Icelandic term, like "oi" is to some English speakers (Australia, Britain etc.)

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this website [blog](http://ohbythewayblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/jonsi-go.html) states that the writer asked about this word and found that it is "a sound that Icelanders make to comfort babies."